# Apontamento CNAME

Tags: dns, domínio

Boa tarde,

Talvez seja uma questão bastante básica, mas sou pouco conhecedor de DNS e preciso esclarecer uma dúvida para não perder tempo com propagação. Vamos lá:

Tenho dois domínios hospedados em dois locais diferentes, digamos um na Locaweb e outro na UOLhost. Vamos chamar de domínios X e Y, respectivamente.O objetivo é que quando meu cliente acessar o endereço www.dominioX.com.br (que já está amplamente divulgado) ele caia no meu site www.dominioY.com.br.

Pensei então em apontar o WWW.dominioX.com.br para o WWW.dominioY.com.br. Considerando que ambos estão hospedados em locais diferentes, eu poderia criar um registro CNAME no dominioX, apontando o nome WWW para WWW.domínioY.com.br ? Seria essa a forma correta?

Obs.: Meu dominioX.com.br hospeda aplicações web de vários clientes, por exemplo: clienteA.dominioX.com.br, clienteB.dominioX.com.br ...

Comment: Se entendi bem dentro do seu domínio X você tem vários subdominios para seus clientes, certo? Então você precisa redirecionar o seu domínio X para o endereço do domínio Y e talvez você tenha que fazer o mesmo para os subdominiosX(clienteA.dominioX.com.br, clienteB.dominioX.com.br...). Se você conseguir criar um CName para o dominioX onde voce possa informar o IP do servidor onde esta o dominio Y, provavelmente vai funcionar. Mas acho que você não terá esta opção. No caso do dominioY o CName funciona porque estão no mesmo servidor.
O mais simples e rápido é fazer o redirecionamento.